# Return PostgreSQL hstore as OrderedDict using psycopg2 in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, hstore

A PostgreSQL hstore maintains order between storage and retrieval. This allows one to define the order in which the keys/values within the hstore are stored and retrieved.

Unfortunately, psycopg2's implementation uses a hard-coded dict under `extras.py -> HstoreAdapter.parse()`.

While in most scenarios parsing an hstore to a dict suites just fine, in our scenario this causes problems; we specifically need to maintain ordering.

One work-around I've derived is querying for keys and values as separate lists:

`SELECT AKEYS(myhstore) AS keys, AVALS(mystoore) AS vals FROM mytbl`

... However that solution treats the symptom of the problem rather than the cause.

Is anyone aware of a monkey-patch solution to this issue, or a branch of psycopg2 which deals with this issue, or of an implementation of the extras.py file which resolves this?

Alternately, does anyone have any other suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTICE: [`HSTORE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html#AEN125161) does not preserve order. It is unordered like Python's `dict`. My previous answer only worked by chance.

> The order of the pairs is not significant (and may not be reproduced on output).

Example:

```
SELECT 'foo=>1,bar=>2,spam=>3,eggs=>4'::hstore
UNION ALL
SELECT hstore('{foo,1,bar,2,spam,3,eggs,4}'::TEXT[])
UNION ALL
SELECT hstore('{{foo,1},{bar,2},{spam,3},{eggs,4}}'::TEXT[])
UNION ALL
SELECT hstore('{foo,bar,spam,eggs}'::TEXT[], '{1,2,3,4}'::TEXT[])
```

All result in:

```
""bar"=>"2", "foo"=>"1", "eggs"=>"4", "spam"=>"3""
""bar"=>"2", "foo"=>"1", "eggs"=>"4", "spam"=>"3""
""bar"=>"2", "foo"=>"1", "eggs"=>"4", "spam"=>"3""
""bar"=>"2", "foo"=>"1", "eggs"=>"4", "spam"=>"3""
```

Which appears to be unordered because its order is different from the original order, and it is not alphabetically ordered.

---

THE BELOW DOES NOT ACTUALLY WORK!

You can maintain order in an `HSTORE` by using the [`hstore_to_matrix()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE) function which converts the `HSTORE` to an array of key-value pairs. Then you have to manually pass it to `OrderedDict` in Python:

```
import collections
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

pg = psycopg2.connect(...)
psycopg2.extras.register_hstore(pg)
cursor = pg.cursor()

cursor.execute("""
    SELECT hstore_to_matrix('a=>1,b=>2,c=>3'::hstore);
""")
pairs = cursor.fetchone()[0]
ordered = collections.OrderedDict(pairs)

print(pairs)
# [['a', '1'], ['b', '2'], ['c', '3']]
print(ordered)
# OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')])
```

`psycopg2` ultimately calls `.keys()` and `.values()` on the dictionary when its converted back to an `HSTORE` which means so long as the dictionary is ordered, the `HSTORE` sent back to PostgreSQL will also be ordered. You just have to pass back an `OrderedDict` instead of a regular `dict` to maintain order:

```
# This will save the data as ordered.
data = OrderedDict([('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')])
cursor.update("""
    UPDATE mytable
    SET ordered = %(data)s;
""", {
    'data': data
})

# This will save the data as unordered. Whatever the internal order
# happens to be for the dict will be sent. When I run it in the python
# interpreter, it results in:
#   [('a', '1'), ('c', '3'), ('b', '2')]
cursor.update("""
    UPDATE mytable
    SET ordered = %(data)s;
""", {
    'data': data
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you could dump to string and store as text

then you could specify `object_pairs_hook` in the json decoder: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders

```
In [1]: json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict).decode('{"foo":1, "bar": 2}')
Out[1]: OrderedDict([('foo', 1), ('bar', 2)])
```

Comment: you're recommending storing as plain text, discarding the hstore data-type as a whole? what if other parts of the system already utilize hstore-specific functionality such as indexes on keys or values, return key/value pairs as individual rows (using `each()`) or use any other hstore-specific functionality? this answer assumes hstore is used as a storage mechanism only, and isn't utilizing even one hstore feature; a very broad and dangerous assumption to make.

Comment: 'could' is hardly a recommendation.  you know your constraints and can take the best approach when given all the options.